Aiogram. Callback на ссылки
Всем привет, вопрос больше общий.
Сейчас разрабатываю бота для телеграм с помощью aiogram. Появилась потребность считать количество переходов по inline-ссылкам (те, что кнопки). Есть ли какой-то способ подклеить callback на такие нажатия?
